# Lightning Flow Query

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I am creating the lightning flow. In which, I need to provide the date in the 'field1' (Type : Date) in the screen component.

In the screen component, the 'field1' should only accept the date value which is in the range of 3years in the past of the current date and 2 years in the future of the current date.

For instance, if a user is entering the value in the 'field1' Date field on 5/13/2021 then the valid date range is between 5/13/2018 thru 5/13/2023.

Can anyone please guide/assist on how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY6Px.png)

To create this date field you need to use following formula

IF(OR(
({!Accepted_Date} <= (DATE(YEAR({!$Flow.CurrentDate}) - 3,MONTH({!$Flow.CurrentDate}),DAY({!$Flow.CurrentDate}) - 1))), ({!Accepted_Date} >= (DATE(YEAR({!$Flow.CurrentDate}) + 2,MONTH({!$Flow.CurrentDate}),DAY({!$Flow.CurrentDate}) + 1)))
), false, true
)